# Error o fallo en los cuadros de texto

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo el HTML de mi ejercico pero al crear las etiquetas para los dados me sale esto. `<`br />**Notice**:  Undefined variable: num2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Tarea1\InterfazPartida.php** on line **60**
`
Este es mi php con el HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>5 magico </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $creditos = 100;

        function partida($creditos) {
            if ($creditos > 9) {
                $creditos = $_POST['creditos'];
                $fichas = 0;
                $creditos -= 10;
                $num1 = math . random_int(0, 9);
                $num2 = math . random_int(0, 9);
                $num3 = math . random_int(0, 9);
                $resultado = array($num1, $num2, $num3);
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultado); $i++) {
                    switch ($resultado[$i]) {
                        case 2:
                            $fichas += 25;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $fichas += 100;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $fichas += 5;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    $creditos += $fichas;
                    $comentario = "has conseguidos $fichas de premio";
                }
            } else {
                $comentario = "no hay suficientes creditos";
            }
            echo $comentario;
            return $creditos;
        }
        ?>
        <p>Tienes <?php echo $creditos; ?>  creditos</p>
        <form name="InferfazPartida" method="post">
            <p>Patida del 5 magico</p>
            <br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="creditos" value="<?php echo $creditos; ?>" />
            <br/>
            <label for="num1">Dado 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" readonly value="<?php echo $num1; ?>"  />

            <label for="num2">Dado 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" readonly value="<?php echo $num2; ?>"  />

            <label for="num1">Dado 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="num3" id="num3" readonly value="<?php echo $num3; ?>"  />

            <input type="submit" value="jugar"/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fíjate que `$num1`, `$num2` y `$num3` están definidas dentro de la función `partida`. Esas variables están fuera de ámbito y por eso no puedes acceder a ellas.

Comment: y como lo hago entonces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si las vas a usar en ese ámbito tendrán que estar al mismo nivel que la variable `$creditos`. Ahora lo que tendrás que hacer es que tu función `partida` devuelva  no solo los créditos, sino cada uno de los números encontrados. Podría ser algo así:

```
$iniciales = 100;

function partida($creditos) {
   // Tú código
   return array($creditos, $num1, $num2, $num3);
}

$resultado = partida($iniciales);
$creditos = $resultado[0];
$num1 = $resultado[1];
$num2 = $resultado[2];
$num3 = $resultado[3];
```

Comment: Si tenemos $iniciales a partida deberia de pasar $iniciales como parametro no?entonces necesitamos en algun sitio uan referencia a que $creditos parte de $inicial no?